# Qt 5.10.0 static build error

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2017, static-linking

I'm trying to build Qt 5.10.0 statically from source on Windows.
I've run Visual Studio 2017 Command Prompt and executed the following command:

```
>configure -static -release -platform win32-msvc
```

But I've got an error:

```
cl -c -Fo./ -Fdqmake.pdb  -W2 -nologo -O1  /MP /wd4577   -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10\qmake -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10\qmake\library -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10\qmake\generators -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10\qmake\generators\unix -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10\qmake\generators\win32 -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10\qmake\generators\mac  -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10/include -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10/include\QtCore -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10/include\QtCore\5.10.1 -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10/include\QtCore\5.10.1\QtCore  -I..\src\corelib\global  -IC:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10\mkspecs\win32-msvc   -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  -DQT_VERSION_STR=\"5.10.1\" -DQT_VERSION_MAJOR=5 -DQT_VERSION_MINOR=10 -DQT_VERSION_PATCH=1  -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DPROEVALUATOR_FULL  -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DUNICODE -c -Yc -Fpqmake_pch.pch -TP C:\qtbase-5.10\qtbase-5.10\qmake\qmake_pch.h
qmake_pch.h
..\src\corelib\global\qglobal.h(63): fatal error C1083: cannot open include file: QtCore/qconfig-bootstrapped.h: No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.EXE" : return code  "0x2"
Stop.
```

What can I do with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should run `configure` from Visual Studio ***Developer Command Prompt***.

You can also open regular command prompt and run following commands before configure

```
CALL "<path inside to your Visual Studio installation>\vcvarsall.bat" x86
SET PATH=<path to Qt sources>\qtbase\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=<path to Qt sources>\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%
```

Use `amd64` instead of `x86` for 64 bit Qt build as *vcvarsall* parameter.
Make sure you have perl and python in your path.